# Jquery waypoints- trigger on page load to an anchor tag

Tags: jquery, triggers, anchor, jquery-waypoints

I've been playing with [waypoints](http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/) and it's pretty handy for long scrolling pages. Navigation elements respond as the user gets further down the page, different options are highlighted in the header, etc.

The problem is there doesn't seem to be a way to reproduce the experience for people that land midway down the page following an `#anchored` link.  I couldn't find documentation to trigger and evaluate the listeners based on the scroll position.

Does that exist?  Is there another way to integrate waypoints with anchored links?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Waypoints works with anchor jumps by default.  I had a Bootstrap class conflict that was interfering.  FWIW I found that the higher in the DOM I attached my waypoint the easier it was to predict how it would behave.